# How to evaluate children in the context of their parents using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do the code below. Essentially, I want to the child to be evaluated in the context of it's parent, so that the references point to the parent. I hope my pseudo-code makes sense.

```
<Comment>
  <UndoButton timeout="120">
    // "this" context would point to UndoButton
    Your comment will post in {this.state.timeLeft} {this.state.timeUnit}.
  </UndoButton>
</Comment>

<Note>
  <UndoButton timeout="60">
    Undo your note for {this.state.timeLeft} more {this.state.timeUnit}.
  </UndoButton>
</Note>

----------------------------

UndoButton = react.createClass
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {timeLeft: this.props.timeout, timeUnit: 'seconds'};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.timer = setInterval(function(){
      var timeUnit;
      var timeLeft = this.state.timeLeft - 1;
      if (timeLeft === 0) {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
      }
      else {
        newState = {timeLeft: timeLeft};
        if (timeLeft === 1) {
          newState.timeUnit = 'second';
        }
        this.setState(newState);
      }
    }, 1000);
  },
  render: function() {
    <div>
      {this.props.children}    // THIS IS WHERE THE MESSAGE WOULD GO
      <button>undo</button>
    </div>
  }
```

Comment: Just pass a function in the properties of the child that is declared in the parent.